# Как применить сразу 2 сортировки

Tags: javascript, сортировка

```js
 $('.list').sort(function (a, b) {
  var contentA = Number($(a).attr('data-bet'));
  var contentB = Number($(b).attr('data-bet'));
  return (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : 0;
 }).appendTo('#coinflip_listings');
 $('.list').sort(function (a, b) {
  var contentA = Number($(a).attr('data-status'));
  var contentB = Number($(b).attr('data-status'));
  return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
 }).appendTo('#coinflip_listings');
```

Как применить 2 сортировки сразу? В первую очередь надо сортировать по `data-status`, а потом уже по `data-bet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете одной сортировкой, сортируете по `data-bet`, на `data-status` смотрите только при равенстве `data-bet`:

```js
$('.list').sort(function(a, b) {
  var contentA = Number($(a).attr('data-status'));
  var contentB = Number($(b).attr('data-status'));
  if (contentA == contentB) {
    var contentStatusA = Number($(a).attr('data-bet'));
    var contentStatusB = Number($(b).attr('data-bet'));
    return (contentStatusA < contentStatusB) ? -1 : (contentStatusA > contentStatusB) ? 1 : 0;
  } else {
    return (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}).appendTo('#coinflip_listings');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list" data-bet="2" data-status="1">bet:2 , status:1</li>
<li class="list" data-bet="3" data-status="0">bet:3 , status:0</li>
<li class="list" data-bet="3" data-status="1">bet:3 , status:1</li>
<li class="list" data-bet="2" data-status="0">bet:2 , status:0</li>
<li class="list" data-bet="1" data-status="0">bet:1 , status:0</li>
<li class="list" data-bet="1" data-status="1">bet:1 , status:1</li>

<ul id="coinflip_listings"></ul>
```

Comment: Смотри как мне надо.. у меня есть data-status 1 и 0. И есть рандомные числа в data-bet. Сообственно надо сделать так, чтобы первыми в списке были data-status=1 (отсортированные по data-bet), а потом уже идут data-status=0 (отсортированные по data-bet).

Comment: Обновил код, проверьте

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо)